# Setting Keyboard Focus to YouTube Embed

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I’m trying to find a way to get the keyboard to focus on the YouTube player in my page. This could, for example, make it easy to use the space bar to play/pause the video.

Here’s an example: [Testing Embed Keyboard Focus (CodePen)](http://codepen.io/jifarris/pen/qOGoVG)

As it is, I’m having to click on the player for it to be able to accept keyboard shortcuts. Because this is not ideal, I’m hoping for a workaround using Javascript or jQuery to set the focus on the video.

I’m aware that – as an alternative – I could use the spacebar key to call the player object's `playVideo` or `pauseVideo` methods, but that still wouldn’t get me access to the full list of the YouTube player’s keyboard controls.

And if this is simply impossible, I’ll understand. But it will be nice to know. Thanks!

Comment: What I’d ultimately like is a way to get the controls to show. Either permanently or when the user engages with a separate in-page element.   


The play/pause and volume up/down keyboard shortcuts show the controls, so that’s why I wanted to use them. (The API functions for each of these actually _don’t_ show the controls.) Perhaps I should start another question for that: Is there any way to make the player controls show in a YouTube embed.

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this to implement whatever hotkeys you want to enable for the player at any rate.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbgeYo

Basically you create an input (can style it so that it blends in, you can't do display:none as that won't let you assign focus), and then attach a keypress event to that input. You then can call functions on the "player" API object which allows you to play/pause etc.

```
var dummy=document.getElementById("dummyFocus");
dummy.focus();
dummy.addEventListener("keypress",function(event){
  if(event.keyCode== 32){
    if(player.getPlayerState() == 1){
      player.pauseVideo();
    }
    else{
      player.playVideo();
    }
  }
});
```

Insert that after you create your player object, and add an input (I used type="button") to the page with id="dummyFocus"

Edit as needed, but that's **a** workaround anyway.

Comment: This is awesome! A great way to allow the spacebar to do play/pause without making it hard for a user to remove focus from the video (to use space for page down, for instance). I really appreciate the suggestion and your example. I played with your example to see if I could get volume adjustments to work, and they did. However, since one of my main objectives was to get the player controls to show (see my new comment on my own post above), I was sad to see that – unlike the built in keyboard shortcuts – the api functions for volume changes _don’t_ show the controls. Anyway, thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

In order to achieve this you would have to `focus()` document embedded in the Youtube's `iframe`. This is restricted by [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) for security reasons.

Here's a piece of code for completeness

```
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    document.querySelector('#player').contentDocument.body.focus(); 
}
```

And it would throw

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property
>   from 'HTMLIFrameElement':

Comment: would do it same as you do

Comment: Okay, I think that makes sense. So that would do it but because of browser security measures it can’t? I’m guessing this also means that focus cannot be achieved through another action, like a hover?

Comment: It does seem that pressing the tab key can get you to it… any chance that means there’s a workaround?

Comment: There is not a work around - you will have to go the route of capturing the keys on the parent page and using the [Player Controls](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_controls) methods that the API provides.  There doesn't seem to be a whole lot that of manual actions missing.