# Focus dynamically created embedded YouTube player

Tags: youtube-api

So I need to open an embedded YouTube player in a website, and I would like to set the focus to the player so that users can interact with the player like for instance toggle the video using the Space key.

```js
var iframe = Object.assign(document.createElement('iframe'), {
  src: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/hLQl3WQQoQ0?autoplay=1&enablejsapi=1',
  width: '400',
  height: '200',
  onload: () => {
    console.log('iframe is loaded!');
    iframe.focus();
  }
});

document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

This code inserts the player, and `onload` is called but the player still does not get the focus. Any idea if this is doable or not?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to focus on the document inside the `iframe` to achieve this, which is not possible due to security reasons.

However, you can add a hidden button `input`, focus on it, and then use `keyCode` and the `player` API from youtube to pause and play the video in the case you press the space bar on that focused input of yours.

Have a look on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34008994/2156532), and on the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbgeYo) it links to.